# QComboBox popup animation glitch

Tags: animation, popup, dropdown, qcombobox, pyside2

When using a QComboBox in PySide2 the popup menu seems to initially start about 10 pixels or so to the left until its finished animating down at which point it pops (about) 10 pixels to the right into the correct position.

How can I fix this? Or am I able to disable the animation so the menu just opens without animating? And am I able to control the animation time for the popup?

Here are two screenshots, the top one is while the combobox dropdown is animating down and the bottom one is after the dropdown is open:

[image: two screenshots of comobobox]

Here's the simple example code use to produce the combobox above:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Modal Dialogs')
        self.setMinimumSize(300,80)

        # remove help icon (question mark) from window
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() ^ QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)

        # create widgets, layouts and connections (signals and slots)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_layouts()
        self.create_connections()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItems(['one','two','three'])

    def create_layouts(self):
        # self must be passed to the main_layout so it is parented to the dialog instance
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        main_layout.addWidget(self.combo)

    def create_connections(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    my_dialog = MyDialog()

    my_dialog.show()  # Show the UI
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you provide an animation or screenshot that highlight the issue? I'm unable to reproduce your issue on my machine.

Comment: Hm i'm just trying it on my mac and its fine. Before I was using windows 10, what os are you on? i'll upload a screenshot tomorrow

Comment: Yes, a screenshot will help a lot :) (I'm on Linux)

Comment: I’ve added a screenshot to my original question

Comment: I'm having the same issue after upgrading my apps to Qt 5.12.1. I have created an issue in the official Qt Bug Tracker: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-74442